# Refresh loses scrolling position on XML page rendered with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, browser, scroll, cross-browser

[This](https://www.jonmsterling.com/) is a publicly available webpage that can be used for testing. It is an XML page transformed into HTML by the browser via XSL transforms.

I noticed that Chrome browsers on MacOS loses the scrolling position on this page upon refreshing. This doesn't happen for plain HTML pages, such as if I use `xsltproc` to pre-render the page into HTML. It also doesn't happen on the XML page on iOS browsers.

What caused this behaviour difference? Is it a bug or a implementation decision? What can I do about it? I can use javascript to remember the scrolling position, as detailed in a number of SO posts. I can also just pre-render the page. But I would like to get to the cause of the matter to see if I'm doing anything wrong with the client-side XML rendering.

Comment: Consider to add a tag for the browser. Or consider to file it as a problem on Chrome or Chromium. Although these days, if it works the way you expect with e.g. Firefox but differently with Chrome in the end Firefox/Mozilla might end up changing their browser to behave the "same" as Chrome instead of Chrome fixing that quirk/bug. That's a bit of sarcasm but I kind of doubt at least that here on StackOverflow someone can help you with some browser behaving a certain way. I doubt it is a technical problem related to the way XSLT/XML is used.

Comment: If there is a difference when you use a different browser than it is probably the HTTP Useragent that need to be set.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent